# How to swap the elements of an array, slice, or Vec?

Tags: arrays, vector, rust, slice

I want to swap elements of slice `data` using library function, but it doesn't work because of multiple borrowing:

```
use std::mem;

fn example() {
    let mut data = [1, 2, 3];
    let i = 0;
    let j = 1;
    
    mem::swap(&mut data[i], &mut data[j]);
}
```

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `data[_]` as mutable more than once at a time
 --> src/lib.rs:8:29
  |
8 |     mem::swap(&mut data[i], &mut data[j]);
  |     --------- ------------  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
  |     |         |
  |     |         first mutable borrow occurs here
  |     first borrow later used by call
  |
```

It could be done manually, but I don't think using this code every time is great:

```rust
let temp = data[i];
data[i] = data[j];
data[j] = temp;
```

Is there any other solution to swap elements in slices?

Comment: *"It could be done manually, as usual"* ... on `Copy` types - otherwise it will result in a "cannot move out of indexed content".

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There's a [`swap` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.swap) on slices: `data.swap(i, j)`.

The original code doesn't work because the language requires that `&mut`s do not alias, that is, if a piece of data is accessible via an `&mut`, then there must be no other way to use that data. In general, for successive indexes `data[i]`, `data[j]`, the compiler cannot guarantee that `i` and `j` are different. If they are the same then the indexing is referring to the same memory and so `&mut data[i]` and `&mut data[j]` would be two pointers to the same data: illegal!

`.swap` uses a bit of `unsafe` code internally, being sure to handle the `i == j` case correctly, avoiding aliasing `&mut` pointers. That said, it doesn't *have* to use `unsafe`, it is only to ensure this "primitive" operation has high-performance (and I could definitely imagine future language/library improvements that reduce the need for unsafe here by making the require invariants easier to express), e.g. the following is a safe implementation:

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::mem;

fn swap<T>(x: &mut [T], i: usize, j: usize) {
    let (lo, hi) = match i.cmp(&j) {
        // no swapping necessary
        Ordering::Equal => return,

        // get the smallest and largest of the two indices
        Ordering::Less => (i, j),
        Ordering::Greater => (j, i),
    };

    let (init, tail) = x.split_at_mut(hi);
    mem::swap(&mut init[lo], &mut tail[0]);
}
```

The key here is `split_at_mut` which separates the slice into two disjoint halves (this is done using `unsafe` internally, but Rust's standard library is built on `unsafe`: the language provides "primitive" features and the libraries build the rest on top of them).

Comment: There is no magic inside - just unsafe block - what a pitty!)

Comment: There is, in ptr mod: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libcore/ptr.rs#L164

Comment: @FominArseniy, it can be implemented with some "magic" to avoid `unsafe` (I've edited my answer to include an example implementation).

Comment: It can also be implemented with using temp variable either, I don't see why there is need in such complex implementation. Problem with double borrowing arises from function call syntax swap(mut & x, mut & y), when x, y point to the same data slice. If function syntax is swap(& mut[], i, j), there is no problem to swap inside of it using temp variable.

Comment: @swizard, this is really dramatical implementation of swap, but it's pointer version.

Comment: @FominArseniy, it only works with a temp variable if the type is `Copy`. If the contained types moves (e.g. `data: &mut [String]`), it is not possible to use the code you give in your question, while the careful one I give does work.

Comment: I think the index `&mut tail[hi]` is wrong, shouldn't it be `&mut tail[0]` ?

Comment: @FominArseniy, yes, it is pointer version which is the slice proc implemented via: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libcore/slice.rs#L352

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use tuple destructing to swap two or more elements in an array.

```rust
// Initial data
let mut data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

// Swap three elements around
(data[1], data[3], data[5]) = (data[3], data[5], data[1]);

// End result
assert_eq!(data, [1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 2]);
```

Comment: This only works if the elements are `Copy`, and should be less performant than `swap()`.